# Odoo, prevent redirecting after web login

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

After I login to odoo from `localhost:8069/web/login` I get redirected to Odoo backend, from where I need to click `Website` to come back to **Home Page**.

How can I prevent this? **I need to stay inside the home page after login.**

**EDIT:**
@moskiSRB 's answer solves the problem for simple login.
But after **Signup** there is auto login which **still** leads to backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna set this for all website users you need to set them to portal users. Also, you can set under `Users->Preferences->Home Action` set to **Website**.

**UPDATE**

For signup new users you need to create template user account and check portal options for that user. Next, go to `Settings->General Settings` under `Portal Access` find `Template user for new users created through signup` choose your template user.

Comment: This works for login. but after signup there is auto login which still leads to backend.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a model that inherits from res.user and modify the action_id with a compute.

```
class InheritResUsers(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.users'
    _inherit = ['res.users']

# Nouveaux champs
action_id = fields.Many2one('ir.actions.actions', string='Home Action', compute='get_home_page')

def get_home_page(self):

    for project in self:
        # we position ourselves in the ir.actions.act_window model
        tasks = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']
        #we search for the specific view by using the name and une xml_id
        task_ids = tasks.search(
            [['xml_id', '=', '  project.open_view_project_all'], ['name', '=', 'Projects']])
        for task in task_ids:  # Browse the table by adding the page id to the inherited action_id field
            self.action_id=task.id
InheritResUsers()
```

Here I redirect to the home page of my module.